# Why doesn't "mvn verify" run my integration tests?

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a multi-module project and I have failsafe defined in the root pom like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
            <include>**/*JourneyTest.java</include>
            <include>**/*CucumberFeatureTest.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*JourneyTest.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*CucumberFeatureTest.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Failsafe is not defined anywhere else in my other poms.  If I run `mvn verify`, it skips integration tests (it runs unit tests).  But if I run `mvn test-compile failsafe:integration-test`, it runs integration tests.

I'm under the assumption that failsafe is supposed to run in both of these situations.  So why doesn't it run when I type `mvn verify`?

**UPDATE**: Just noticed that this was wrapped around these tags:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement> <!-- oops -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
```

I feel like this explains the cause, but I'm not sure why *unit* tests still run like you'd expect with `mvn verify` and `mvn test`.  Why does surefire work differently from failsafe in this respect?

Comment: I believe Surefire is included in the standard POM but Failsafe is not.

Comment: I had the same problem with the pluginManagement.

Answer (score 12):

You need to bind failsafe's integration test goal to maven's `integration-test` and `verify` phases.  By default the failsafe-plugin isn't included in a `vanilla` maven project.  You need to add it.  So even though there is an `integration-test` lifecycle, by default it is not included (well, at least doesn't run the `maven-failsafe-plugin`).  You add it to the `integration-test` and `verify` phases (it needs both, it will fail the build at the `verify` phase only [if the preceding integration-tests failed], so that the `post-integration` lifecycle phase still has a chance to run and cleanup resources, hence the name "fail safe").

```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.19</version>
       <configuration>
           <includes>
               <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
               <include>**/*JourneyTest.java</include>
               <include>**/*CucumberFeatureTest.java</include>
           </includes>
       </configuration>
       <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
   </plugin>
```

Comment: That change had no affect on the outcome.  I'll update the original question to include this

Comment: Yes, binding the failsafe plugin to the execution is the correct solution.  Unfortunately, as with a lot of Maven documentation, it's not pointed out well enough.  This setup is documented in the [failsafe plugin's official docs](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: For followers, see Daniel Kaplan's "update" to the question for why it didn't affect his outcome (but is the right answer nonetheless).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue when running mvn verify as the integration tests were not executed, but only the unit tests.
It worked after marking **skipTests** to **false**:

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>           
</plugin>
```