# Use Karate framework with Fail Safe and Sure Fire plugin

Tags: java, maven, karate

I am currently moving a Restful web service project from Rest assured testing framework to Karate.

We are reporting code coverage using Jacoco and use the Sure fire plugin for running the unit test and Fail safe plugin for running the Rest assured integration test .

The unit test cases are .java files and integration test in Karate are .feature files .

Can we configure the Karate framework in pom file to use Surefire plugin to run the unit test cases and fail safe plugin to run the Karate integration test and then run the integration test using the command

mvn test -Dtest= Runnerpgm

Trying to set up the above is giving error ,

" Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test(default test) on project xxxxx :No tests were executed"

The sample projects in intuit/Karate shows Karate integration tests with Jacoco using surefire plugin only .

Comment: closed as duplicate, also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59082487/143475 - open a new question with specifics if needed