# Karate with Failsafe plugin, features are not being found

Tags: java, karate

I hope someone can help me, it seems a silly issue, but I have not been able to make Karate running on my project.
I want to use Karate to perform the Integration Test, calling REST Services, whose implementation is provided by another module in the same project.
I am using Karate with JUnit5 configuration.
I have the following Maven project structure:

[image]

You can also see above my pom.xml in the EAR module.

I am using *weblogic-maven-plugin*, because I need to deploy the EAR artifact before starting the Integration Test.

The main pom.xml contains the plugin configuration as you can see below:

[image]

I followed the instructions on https://github.com/intuit/karate#quickstart and also created the skeleton project using the Karate Maven archetype to compare the configuration.

When I run *mvn verify* I get this output:

[image]

My runner test class is:

[image]

The test class is being executed, but for some reason the feature file is not being found.

What might be the problem ?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.
Brienze

Comment: You probably missed the `test-resources` tweak: https://github.com/intuit/karate#folder-structure Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48522439/143475

Comment: Hello @PeterThomas, I could have it working through this https://github.com/khmarbaise/maui/issues/2. It is mentioned in the second link you suggested. Nice, this way I don´t need to create a separated module, then it would be necessary to manage the deployment through script. Thanks a lot. Now I will start playing with Karate ! :-)